# problem with determining data type of query column in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have written below query in hibernate and it is giving me NullPointerException

```
SELECT new com.reddy.ReddyDTO( col1, IF(STRCMP(COL8, 'zero')=0, 'string', col2) ) 
FROM entity
```

However it is throwing me NPE as it was unable to determine data type for second column as String type.

I can see that it was unable to determine a type by looking at below location
in `org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(String path)` method, the field `constructorArgumentTypes` is having values `(org.hibernate.type.StringType, null)`

How to make hibernate understand this column is of String data type?
(I have already trying to put "string" in double-quotes, but that is giving me error)

Comment: It is working with case statement, problem is that IF is not available in HQL.

Comment: SELECT new com.reddy.ReddyDTO(col1, case col8 when 'zero' then 'string' else col2 end) FROM entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... What is this `IF` expression? I can't find it in the reference documentation. To my knowledge, the closest would be a `case` expression:

> "Simple" case, case ... when ... then ... else ... end, and "searched" case, case when ... then ... else ... end

<strike>But I doubt you can use this in a constructor expression.</strike>

**Update:** It appears Hibernate is better than I thought, you *can* use a case in a constructor expression:

```
SELECT new com.reddy.ReddyDTO(col1, case col8 when 'zero' then 'string' else col2 end) FROM entity
```

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Comment: hmm... I am using MySQL and, first part in the IF is condition, second value is if the condition is true, and other one is if condition is false. Will check with case also, if it allows me to compare string values.

Comment: @Reddy You're using HQL here - not native SQL - and HQL doesn't have an IF expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a database function in your select statement that hibernate is not aware of, you have to define it in your `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` in order for hibernate to determine the correct return type.

All you have to do is overwrite your dialect, say `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`, and create a constructor like this:

```
public MySQL5InnoDBDialectExt() {
    super();
    registerFunction("if_str", new StandardSQLFunction("if", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    registerFunction("if_int", new StandardSQLFunction("if", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
    registerFunction("if_float", new StandardSQLFunction("if", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE));
    registerFunction("strcmp", new StandardSQLFunction("strcmp", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
}
```

Unfortunately, you have to define several function for different return types (if you need it), since hibernate is only able to determine the return type dynamically, if it corresponds to the type of the first argument, which is not the case here.

After setting the `hibernate.dialect` property in `hibernate.cfg.xml` your query should work now (note the use of `IF_STR` instead of `IF`):

```
SELECT new com.reddy.ReddyDTO( col1, IF_STR(STRCMP(COL8, 'zero')=0, 'string', col2) ) 
FROM entity
```