# Please provide example for an If statement in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How do you write criteria on if condition using hibernate criteria.

My query that needs to be transformed is

```
SELECT date, product, IF(type = 'msrp', amount, 0) price, 
     IF(type != 'msrp', amount, 0) tax FROM productdetail group by date, product;
```

Please provide the right usage of **if statement** in hibernate criteria.

Comment: This is not supported by the criteria API. You'll have to implement your own projection (if possible, I haven't checked the API) if you need that.

Answer (score 5):

As @JBnizet said,**This is not supported by the criteria API.** unless you are using `NHibernate`

if your using NHIbernate

```
  Projections.Conditional(
         Restrictions.EqProperty(..............
```

But here are my possible solutions with Hibernate.

1)You can use the same query By using [NativeSqlQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) in such type of situations

2)Or by using HQL.There is  an [expression in HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) called `case when`.This might be helpful [Using a CASE statement in HQL select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456181/using-a-case-statement-in-hql-select)

Answer (score 0):

The standard workaround for union queries is a View table, otherwise it is 2 criteria and logic in java to manipulate the results.