# Hibernate Criteria Projection Property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate Criteria Projections Property.
I want to test '**IS NULL**' condition before adding into Projection List.

Consider sample example

```
.add(Projections.property("normalRange"),"normalRange")
```

i want to test this property value IS NULL and do some operations

(i.e) in Mysql

```
IF(normalRange IS NULL,testRange,normalRange) as normalRange
```

How to achieve this query in my Hibernate criteria ?

I hope my questions is clear. Please Help !

Comment: I don't think so there is way to do this. You have to use native SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please provide example for an If statement in hibernate criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826567/please-provide-example-for-an-if-statement-in-hibernate-criteria)