# HIbernate criteria builder sum with if condition

Tags: java, sql, spring, criteria-api

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(table.type='type1', 1, 0)) as type1,SUM(IF(table.type='type2', 1, 0)) as type2 from table;
```

How to write same query in criteria builder like below:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery( Object[].class );
Root<Table> root = criteria.from( Table.class );
criteria.multiselect(builder.sum())
```

I am unable to place if condition in criteria builder.

Note: there is bean class for Table.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [hibernate criteria does not support IF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826567/please-provide-example-for-an-if-statement-in-hibernate-criteria). I would consider just making 2 queries with criteria or using HQL or just native SQL.