# case ..when query in hql

Tags: java, hql

I have to check `null` against the entry. 

I have address in person object, so I have tried to fetch it like below.

```
select new map(person.id as id,
               case when person.address is not empty 
               then person.address.city end as city) 
from Person person where person.id=:id
```

Does `case..when` work with `where` clause

But there is no error and result.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456181/using-a-case-statement-in-hql-select

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select new map(person.id as id,coalesce(person.address,person.address.city )as city) from Person person
```