# Using case while doing select in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I know case can be used as expression in where clause of HQL.

I read through this thread [Using a CASE statement in HQL select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456181/using-a-case-statement-in-hql-select)

In a way my question is duplicate

Is it possible to use them in the select part of HQL with hibernate 4 or 5. I know its not possible with Hibernate 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

There is a [dedicated section in the Hibernate 5 Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-case-expressions) you can take a look as well as [in this section for Hibernate 4.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3289).

According to the [changelog.txt](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/changelog.txt#L4341) it was added back in version **3.0** though not in the form it has evolve to today ([SimpleCaseExpression](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/criteria/internal/expression/SimpleCaseExpression.java), [SearchedCaseExpression](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/criteria/internal/expression/SearchedCaseExpression.java))

Comment: thanks for the references. Can you please add info (if you know) since which version of hibernate it is allowed.