# Hibernate - perform case - select for property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables in my DB: Customers and Companies.

Mapping for Customer:

```
<class name="CustomerModel" table="CUSTOMERS" mutable="false">

    <cache usage="transactional"/>

    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" precision="19" scale="0"/>
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="company" not-null="true" column="CUSTOMER_COMP_ID" class="CompanyModel" />

    <property name="type"  type="CustomerType">
        <column name="TYPE"/>
    </property>

    <property name="fullName" type="string">
        <column name="FULL_NAME"/>
    </property> 

</class>
```

TYPE column/property can contains two values: PERSON, COMPANY

And for Company:

```
<class name="CompanyModel" table="COMPANIES" mutable="false">

    <cache usage="transactional"/>

    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="ID" precision="19" scale="0" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="NAME"/>
    </property>

</class>
```

I want to create **formula** for property **fullName** in **CustomerModel** which:

- when type = 'PERSON' then fullName = fullName (do not change it)
- when type = 'COPMANY' then funnName = company.name

How to create such formula?

Comment: please elaborate more on what you would like to achieve, in current form of your question it is hard to deduce what your are asking.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki - you are right, fixed :)

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456181/using-a-case-statement-in-hql-select